# Transform column name multindex in one column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, rename

I have this dataframe

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({'At': ['A','B','C'], 
                   'R': ['27,0', '27,0', '27,0'], 
                   'V1': [0,0,0], 
                   'V2': [100,32,72], 'V3':[31,12,3]})

  At     R  V1   V2  V3
0  A  27,0   0  100  31
1  B  27,0   0   32  12
2  C  27,0   0   72   3
```

Then i make a pivot table

```
dt.pivot_table(index='At', columns='R', 
               values=['V1','V2','V3']).reset_index()
  At   V1   V2   V3
R    27,0 27,0 27,0
0  A    0  100   31
1  B    0   32   12
2  C    0   72    3
```

I want to concat my multindex columns name like this

```
  At   27,0_V1   27,0_V2   27,0_V3
0  A       0       100        31
1  B       0        32        12
2  C       0        72         3
```

It's only a sample, i have more than one level

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manipulate the headers a bit; use `swaplevel` + `MultiIndex.map`:

```
v = dt.pivot_table(index='At', columns='R', 
               values=['V1','V2','V3']).reset_index()

v.columns =  v.columns.swaplevel().map('_'.join).str.strip('_')
```

Or, as Scott Boston suggests,

```
v.columns = v.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format).str.strip('_')
```

```
v
  At  27,0_V1  27,0_V2  27,0_V3
0  A        0      100       31
1  B        0       32       12
2  C        0       72        3
```

Comment: You can use format instead of swaplevel, `pdt.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format).str.strip('_')`